# Entitiy Framework - DB round trips

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I would like to know if exists a way to log all DB trips from Entity Framework.

I have google it, but I didn't found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EFTracingProvider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers) from MSDN code gallery.

Answer (score 2):

This tool might be able to help. It will give you more information than just that. This profiler will let you see the SQL queries being sent to the database as well as plenty of other information.

http://www.efprof.com/

Comment: efprof is a great tool. WOrth the $$. And using the subscription, it doesn't cost that much really....